# Antimicrobial susceptibility testing

Tags: experimental-design, antibiotics

To learn the Kirby-Bauer method, I've been looking at [youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np87w5kCL-4) where a bacteria's susceptibility is tested.

In this video, the researcher places the discs (containing antibiotics) right after she inoculates the lawn on the agar disk. Shouldn't you wait until the bacteria has grown before adding the disk containing antibiotics?

Comment: That's "a fungus" or plural "fungi"; I can't tell if the rest of your question also has the same type of error for "bacteria" or what you are actually trying to ask.

Comment: No; antimicrobial discs are almost always added at the time of plating. The antimicrobials will *prevent* growth. This covers both bacteriostatic and bacteriocidal antimicrobial agents. If you were trying to differentiate between bacteriostatic and bacteriocidal, I suppose you *could* treat with the antimicrobial only after growth. What are you actually trying to test? What is the purpose of your experiment? Can you give us more details?

Comment: Rarely do you have a single bacterium, @tripleee; multiple colonies, even of the same species, are typically referred to in plural.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm trying to test the susceptibility of the fungi M.furfur against different concentrations of neem extract. If I added the disks right after the inoculation, wouldn't the bacteria be killed even before it has grown? How would zone of inhibition occur if it has already been killed?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely the idea. The bacteria is not able to grow around the disc, because the antibacterial is inhibiting its growth. The zone of inhibition shows how effective the antibacterial is at inhibiting growth of the bacteria. Because a *lawn* was plated, the bacteria will be able to grow everywhere else that it is not being exposed to the antibacterial agent from the disc. Google for "disk diffusion test" or "Kirby-Bauer test" for more details; e.g., [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_diffusion_test).

Answer (score 1):

A more useful question to ask would be, Why do you place the disc on the plate before the bacteria have grown up? This test allows us to infer which antibiotics an organism is susceptible and resistant to by observing whether or not they grow in the presence of that given antibiotic.

But there's a good reason we don't wait until the bacteria are already grown and see which antibiotics kill it. The metabolic activity of bacteria growing on a plate will slow as their population grows and available nutrients are locally depleted. However, the most common modes of antibiotic action only function well when the target organism is metabolically active. So we apply the antibiotics at the same time the culture is inoculated to ensure some level of metabolic activity is going to be happening.

For example, Betalactams disrupt cell-wall synthesis but don't destroy existing cell walls. If the target population is largely dormant, there will be minimal cell-wall synthesis occurring, and any bactericidal effects would be difficult to detect, if not completely absent. The same goes for antibiotics that disrupt translation (aminoglycosides and tetracyclines), prevent nucleic acid synthesis (Quinolones), or interfere with synthesis of specific metabolites (Sulfonamides). Those are all disruptions of metabolic activity that are necessary during growth and reproduction, but largely shut down during dormancy. Some bacterial populations even take advantage of this loop-hole by maintaining a small proportion of their population as metabolically inactive ["persister" cells.](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrmicro1557#:%7E:text=Bacterial%20populations%20produce%20persisters%2C%20which,treatment%20by%20all%20known%20antimicrobials.)